# Saving API response as PDF - encoding problem

Tags: php, json, pdf, curl, encoding

I'm trying to save a REST API response ([documentation](https://docs.inpost24.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=12091525) - Polish only) as a PDF file on a server using PHP curl request. The following code gives response status 200 which means the API provides me with a binary PDF shipping label.

The problem is that json_last_error_msg() says "Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded" and the PDF file saved on the server is corrupted.

Am I doing something wrong or missing something?

```
$url = "https://api-shipx-pl.easypack24.net/v1/shipments/314718872/label?format=Pdf&type=normal";
   
$headr[] = 'Content-type: application/json';
$headr[] = 'Authorization: Bearer '.$accesstoken; //the token is defined elsewhere ofc
   
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headr);
$json_response = curl_exec($curl);
$status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($curl);
   
echo "Response status: " . $status . "<br>"; //that echoes 200
   
$response = json_decode($json_response, true);
   
echo "Error: " . json_last_error_msg() . "<br>"; //that's Malformed UTF-8...
   
$pdfData = base64_decode($json_response);
file_put_contents('some_test_label.pdf', $pdfData);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! **A PDF is not a JSON or a JSON response,** so you can't JSON decode it. Remove the line that calls `json_decode`. You should also rename the `$json_response` variable, because the response is not a JSON response.

Comment: As for the PDF being saved corrupted on the server, try saving the file without `base64_decode`.

Comment: Of course. Thank you for that warm welcome and precious help! I think I can't mark your comment as a solution but at least I'm gonna edit my post so others can see the working code. Cheers!

Comment: Don't edit the original question. You are allowed to answer your own question if you figured out the solution yourself, try it.

Comment: Right, done. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Jonathan solved the problem. The working code below:

```
$url = "https://api-shipx-pl.easypack24.net/v1/shipments/314718872/label?format=Pdf&type=normal";

$headr[] = 'Content-type: application/json';
$headr[] = 'Authorization: Bearer '.$accesstoken; //the token is defined elsewhere ofc

$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headr);
$response = curl_exec($curl);
$status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($curl);

echo "Response status: " . $status . "<br><br>";
echo "Encoding: " . mb_detect_encoding($response) . "<br>";
echo "Error: " . json_last_error_msg() . "<br>";

file_put_contents('some_test_label.pdf', $response);
```